# Is there an opencl profiler for mac os X 10.8?

Tags: macos, opencl, osx-mountain-lion, gpu

I am trying to find the bottleneck in my OpenCL kernel, is it possible to profile OpenCL programms on mac os X? I found gDebugger on http://www.gremedy.com/, but it requires 10.5 or 10.6 to run. AMD SDK supports only Linux and Windows.

Is there a profiler for Mountain Lion?

Comment: Hi Pavel, did my answer help you?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need a real profiler/analyzer to see which part of the kernel code must be improved.

Answer (score 1):

How detailed must your profiling information be?
Is it okay to use the built-in internal profiler?
OpenCL queues can be created with the CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE flag.

This way you can see for each kernel you executed:
When it has been

- Enqueued
- Submitted to you OCL-Device
- Started
- Ended

With **C++-Bindings**, the creation of the queue can look like this:

```cpp
_queue = new cl::CommandQueue(_context, _device, CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE );
```

The extration of the profiling information looks like this:

1) Save the event object (in an array) delivered by the enqueued kernel you want to profile.

```cpp
cl::Event evt;
_queue->enqueueNDRangeKernel( _kernel, cl::NullRange, _range, cl::NullRange, NULL, &evt);
```

2) After execution of the queue, extract the profiling information

```cpp
std::vector<cl::Event> evts;

//add all events to this vector here
//cl::Event evt;
//_queue->enqueueNDRangeKernel( _kernel, cl::NullRange, _range, cl::NullRange, NULL, &evt); 
//evts.push_back(evt);

uint64_t param;
for (unsigned int i=0; i<evts.size(); i++)
{
    evts[i].getProfilingInfo(CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_QUEUED, &param);
    printf("%u: %llu", i, param);
    evts[i].getProfilingInfo(CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_SUBMIT, &param);
    printf(" %llu", param);
    evts[i].getProfilingInfo(CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, &param);
    printf(" %llu", param);
    evts[i].getProfilingInfo(CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, &param);
    printf(" %llu\n", param);
}
```