# Profiling OpenCL on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, profiling, opencl, gpgpu

I need to find out where my kernel is spending the most amount of time. Can someone please tell if there is a way to do it in Mac OS X (Darwin). This has been asked before: [Is there an opencl profiler for mac os X 10.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771567/is-there-an-opencl-profiler-for-mac-os-x-10-8)

The answer explains how to profile using OpenCL's inbuilt profiler, but that will not give me the kind of detail that I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

NVIDIA's Nsight Eclipse Edition can do a limited amount of OpenCL profiling under Mac OS X. I'm not sure if it gives line-by-line detail like you want though.